# SQL INSERT is not working in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

nice to meet you all! I'm trying to make a simple 'upload' form to INSERT product data into a database. But execute() always returns false.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="?catalogue=1" method="post">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input placeholder="Produktname" type="text" id="productName" size="40" maxlength="50" name="productName" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input placeholder="Produktbeschreibung" type="text" id="productDesc" size="40" maxlength="2000" name="productDesc" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input placeholder="Preis pro KG" type="number" id="price_KG" size="1" maxlength="5" name="price_KG" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    <input placeholder="Bild-URL" type="url" id="productIMG" size="40" maxlength="200" name="productIMG">
    </div>

    </div>


    <button class="" type="submit">Hinzufügen <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </form>

    </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php


        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_name = 'shop';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_password = 'root';
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);

        if(isset($_GET['catalogue'])) {
            $error = false;
            $productName = trim($_POST['productName']);
            $productDesc = trim($_POST['productDesc']);
            $priceKG = $_POST['price_KG'];
            $productIMG = trim($_POST['productIMG']);

            if(empty($productName) || empty($productDesc) || empty($priceKG) || empty($productIMG)) {
                echo 'Bitte alle Felder ausfüllen<br>';
                $error = true;
            }

            if(!$error) {   


                $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (productName, productDesc, price_KG, productIMG) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $result = $statement->execute(array($productName, $productDesc, $priceKG, $productIMG));

                if($result) {       
                    echo 'Produkt wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt.';
                    echo $productName, $productDesc, $priceKG, $productIMG;
                } else {
                    echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';
                }
            } 


        }       
?>
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `productDesc` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price/KG` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productImg` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `productName` (`productName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: For one thing, your column is called `price/KG` and you're inserting into `price_KG`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The mistake was the unmatching column price_KG and price/KG
Sorry for bothering!

Comment: That is because `price_KG` does not exist

Comment: You guys are great haha! Have been sitting here for hours, thanks!

Comment: `PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION])`